# Do I really need Web Platform Installer in my Path environment variable

Tags: path, web-platform-installer

I'm not sure how this got onto my path:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\

but it did, and now I want to know if I can safely remove it.  Why is it there, and what, if any, negative side effects can I expect if I remove it from my path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not planning on developing web applications or content, you will not need it. its primarilly used for installing components for web services like IIS server, SQL Server, Content management systems like Drupal, etc.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx